# Issue declaring a function component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to declare a function component in React, so that I could use my custom hook for making API calls. I'm getting a `rules-of-hooks` that my hook `useGet` cannot be called inside a callback. In my eyes I am declaring a function component, I must be missing something?

Example:

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { getData } = useGet("myUrl");
    setData(getData);
  }, [getData]);


  return (
     <div>{data}</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You're calling `useGet` inside `useEffect`, move the `useGet` out of `useEffect`.

Comment: Moreover using a `useState` hook in `useEffect` hooks creates an infinite loop, so you should avoid that also.

Comment: Hooks cannot be called inside of an effect. It must be a top-level call from within the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call hooks inside useEffect. Just move it above the call like so:

```
const { getData } = useGet("myUrl");

useEffect(() => {    
    setData(getData);
  }, [getData]);
```

As far as I understand, the number of hooks needs to be always the same in your component. Calling some in useEffect might result in the hooks sometimes being called and sometimes not, as useEffect depends on changing the values of variables.

(Also - just as a side note - in your code in `useEffect(()=>{const { getData } = useGet("myUrl");...}, [getData])` you would be checking for changes in a variable (getData) that is not declared yet. This does get fixed once you place the hook call outside the useEffect though.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you actually invoke your custom hook from inside a callback which is inside useEffect.
We should call react hooks on the top level of a component function.

Maybe it is better not to use a hook but just create and import fetching function or call fetch api right from inside useEffect like that
https://designcode.io/react-hooks-handbook-fetch-data-from-an-api

Answer (score 1):

It's true that hooks can only be called in functional components, but hooks also need to be called at the top level of a component. You're trying to call useGet inside the useEffect, which is not allowed. If I'm not mistaken you can probably just move the line `const {getData} = useGet("myUrl");` 2 rows up and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in having created a functional component.

Let's go back to the official React documentation and look at the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

> **Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**
>
> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
> Instead, **always use Hooks at the top level of your React function**,
> before any early returns.

Calling hooks at any location that is **not** the top level will cause unexpected behavior.